# Boldface for undescore in math mode

Tags: math-mode, bold, subscripts

I need to insert an equation which contains the term
`x_y` (`y` is subscript). The term must also be boldfaced.

How do I achieve this in LaTeX?

Comment: `\bm{x_y}` with `bm` package would work

Comment: Oh! Thanks, it worked :) Sorry, I should have googled better..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\bm{x_y}` with `bm` package would work